# Reset formatting on React styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx, styled-components

I'm doing:

```
const Hint = styled.div`
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  color: grey;
  span {
    color: black;
  }
`
```

Then, in render() do as follows:

```
<Hint>
  Hint: Use <span>TEXT TO RESET FORMATTING</span> to send a message 
</Hint>
```

Is there more elegant way to reset formatting of some text inside the styled component ?

Comment: What do you mean _reset the formatting_?

Comment: make color initial instead of grey